# How to use with closure in updating the entities of an object?

Tags: groovy, closures, block

Using the `with closure` is possible in creating new Instance of an object easier and simpler as stated [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#with%28groovy.lang.Closure%29). But how can I use this closure when updating the entity values of my object?
Say I want to update the fields of my Person object that has an id = 1.

```
def p = Person.findById(1)
p.fname = 'First'
p.lname = 'Last'
p.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like:

```
Person.findById(1).with {
  fname = 'First'
  lname = 'Last'
  save()
}
```

It's not 100% clear from the question that this is what you mean...

Comment: Thanks. I have already tried your codes above, but this didn't work, that's why I posted this query. Same code with yours gives me this error , "Cannot make an immutable entity modifiable." That's why I'm wondering if I am using the with closure properly whenever I want to update the entities of my object. Thanks :)

Comment: I get the problem. I got this error message because my domain class is in cache read-only setting. Thanks :)

Comment: @chemilleX3 I was going to ask if [it was this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699393/grails-data-binding-cannot-make-an-immutable-entity-modifiable) ;-)  Glad you got it working!